# android textview contents off screen

Tags: android, textview, trim

In my video player i have three textviews (title , battery percentage, time). The problem is the time text getting trimmed when title text is too long. How to fix this? is there is any solution to dynamically adjust the textview length and positions? Here is my code and screenshot---

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#45000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/batPer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="100%"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timetxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"

                android:text="03:07AM"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you can assign weigh to each TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout`. as well as you can assign `android:ellipsize="marquee"` or `android:ellipsize="end"` to the First `title_txt`

Even I had changed the width of `LinearLayout` containing Battery Percentage and Timer from `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

doesn't matter your text of title increase or decrease timer and and percentage will remain at the right side.

Try With Following Code.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/top_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#45000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll_timer_battery_perc"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_timer_battery_perc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/batPer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="100%"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timetxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="03:07AM"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using android:lines="1" which makes text get trimmed if longer than one line. You should remove this or extend to 2 lines if you want the text to fit the textview and all be displahed

Comment: It should be one line for all textviews. any other solution?

Comment: any way to trim the title text when it touches the battery percentage text??

Comment: You could specify a layout weight to do that, so that the textview will never exceed the linearlayout containing the battery text and time. Of course text that is too long will still be trimmed. http://www.chess-ix.com/blog/the-use-of-layout_weight-with-android-layouts/

Answer (score 1):

Change this way by using `Weight`.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/batPer"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="100%"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timetxt"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="03:07AM"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```